# R: Create Data Partition with extra term

Tags: r, r-caret

I have the following data.frame (which is longer then the following example)

```
sub height  group
1   1.55    a
2   1.65    a
3   1.76    b
4   1.77    a
5   1.58    c
6   1.65    d
7   1.82    c
8   1.91    c
9   1.77    b
10  1.69    b
11  1.74    a
12  1.75    c
```

Im making a data partition with the following code:

```
library("caret")
train = createDataPartition(df$group, p = 0.50)
partition = df[train, ]
```

So it takes a subject with the probability of 0.5 from each group.
My problem is in this following example is that sometimes a subject from group d will be picked and sometimes not (because group d is really small). I want to create a constraint that in every partition I make, atlist 1 subject from EVERY group will be picked.

Any graceful solution?

I came up with a not-so graceful solution looking like this:

```
allGroupSamles <- c()
for (i in unique(df$groups))
{
  allGroupSamles <- c(allGroupSamles , sample(rownames(df[df$groups == i, ]) , 1, replace = TRUE))
}
allGroupSamles <- as.integer(allGroupSamles )

train = createDataPartition(df$groups, p = 0.50)[[1]]
train <- c(allGroupSamles , train)

partition= df[unique(train), ]
```

Comment: Check out `library(dplyr)`.  I think `group_by()` and `sample_n()` fit your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` on a `data.frame` and sample within each group taking half of the records or 1, whichever is greater:

```
# apply a function over the split data.frame
samples <- lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) {

  # the function takes a random sample of half the records in each group
  # by using `ceiling`, it guarantees at least one record
  s <- sample(nrow(x), ceiling(nrow(x)/2))
  x[s,]
})

train <- do.call(rbind, samples)
```

## Edit:

If you need a numeric vector:

```
s <- tapply(1:nrow(df), df$group, function(x) {
  sample(x, ceiling(length(x)/2))
})

do.call(c, s)
```

Comment: Wow.. That is gracful.. My solution works but its not close to be as good as this one.. amazing.

Comment: Do you think I should extract out the function from the tapply if Im iterating these lines over 100 iterations?

Comment: I'm not sure what the performance difference would be. I would test it both ways and compare the execution time using the `microbenchmark` library. I don't think `R` is re-defining the function every iteration, if that's what concerns you